# Viewing Same stories in different boards

Tags: azure-devops

I'm trying to get the same user stories to show up in different boards within the same project.  I checked the mapping and everything seems to be ok so I'm not sure what the issue is.  Anyone have any suggestions on what to check?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to get the same user stories to show up in different boards within the same project.

Azure boards are divided by team and work items are allocated based the Area Path of the team.

To see the same work items in different boards, you could try the following steps.

Step1: Navigate to **Project Settings -> Team configuration** . Select target teams and check if the teams have the same area path.

[image]

Step2: Open the work item that needs to be shared between Boards. Set the area path as the shared area path.

[image]

Then you could view the same User Stories in different boards.